# How to only print one copy of the array?

Tags: php, arrays, echo

The biggest problem is that I don't know what words to use. I think I'm looking for an argument or a flag...?

I'm getting an array back from a database fetch and the array stores each value twice, once with a word key and once with a number key..

```
[0] => Value1
[FirstEntry] => Value1
[1] => Value 2
[SecondEntry] => Value2
```

I'd like the array to only contain (fetch), or only print, either/or entry of Value1, but not both entries of Value1. How can I do this in PHP, preferably during the PDO fetch or during the print_r/echo loop? Thank you.

Comment: show us the code you have or error you get

Comment: Fetch the data using only a single fetch method, not both

Comment: There's no error it's just not behaving how I need it to. This is the code.

    while($r = $query->fetch()) {
        print_r($r);
    }

Comment: Phil can you elaborate?! You're saying exactly what I want to do but I don't know how to do it! WTF a fetch method???

Comment: `$statment->fetch(PDO:FETCH_BOTH)` is default, so you're getting both associative and numeric properties and values. I would use `$statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)` and just use the Object approach if I was using PDO.

Comment: I see now thank you!

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are fetching data using a *"both"* fetch style, ie `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`, `MYSQLI_BOTH`, etc. These tend to be the default fetch styles.

If you just want a single style of index, use either a *"num"* **or** *"assoc"* style.

For example

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare(...);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Use This comments (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) get unique Key Array From return From Data Base  ..